# Spark AWS EMR returns "Class Not Found" error

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to deploy a Spark application to a running EMR cluster from a jar file that is located in S3.  I can get the proper execution if I set `master` to `local[*]` (when deploying in client or cluster mode).  However, as soon as I remove this, I get this error on both slave nodes in the cluster:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.package.other.App$
```

Here's the command I'm trying to run in the AWS Add Step dialog:

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --class com.package.other.App s3://bucket/dir/my-assembly-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I have checked the environment tab in the Spark History Server Web UI and I see this row:

```
spark.jars  file:/tmp/tmp8304655502438853488/dir/my-assembly-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

And in the logs under Yarn executor launch context:

```
resources:
    __app__.jar -> resource { scheme: "hdfs" host: "XXXXX.ec2.internal" port: PORT file: "/user/hadoop/.sparkStaging/application_1505928232504_0022/my-assembly-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" }
```

Shouldn't that mean that the main class is accessible on these nodes?  I've tried running spark-submit locally on the the cluster master node and referencing the jar file that is copied to the master node and I get the same error.